# psmatrix circles not appearing

Tags: beamer, pstricks

the following code

```
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{255, 73, 93}
\newcommand{\mytextsizesmaller}{\srcsizesix}

\begin{center}
\centering
\psmatrix[mnode=Circle,radius=6pt,colsep=0.5cm,rowsep=0.25cm,fillcolor=myred!95,fillstyle=solid,linewidth=0.5pt]
\mytextsizesmaller 2  &                                          & \mytextsizesmaller3                     & \mytextsizesmaller\ldots              &   & \mytextsizesmaller n-1   \\ 
                      & [fillcolor=platinum]\mytextsizesmaller   & [fillcolor=platinum]\mytextsizesmaller  & [fillcolor=platinum]\mytextsizesmaller& [fillcolor=platinum]\mytextsizesmaller           \\  
\mytextsizesmaller1   &                                          &                                         &                                       &   & \mytextsizesmaller n   \\
\endpsmatrix     
\ncline[linewidth=0.25pt]{-}{1,1}{2,2} 
\ncline[linewidth=0.25pt]{-}{3,1}{2,2} 
\ncline[linewidth=0.25pt]{-}{2,2}{2,3} 
\ncline[linewidth=0.25pt]{-}{2,3}{2,4}
\ncline[linewidth=0.25pt]{-}{1,3}{2,3}
\ncline[linewidth=0.25pt]{-}{1,4}{2,4}
\ncline[linewidth=0.25pt]{-}{2,4}{2,5}
\ncline[linewidth=0.25pt]{-}{1,6}{2,5}
\ncline[linewidth=0.25pt]{-}{3,6}{2,5}
\end{center}
```

previously working properly in beamer (xelatex compiler) suddenly stopped to work today after an update of tex live utility.

In particular, the circles do not appear anymore. The only way to make them show up again is to remove the option

fillcolor=myred!95,fillstyle=solid

which however is necessary in my case.

Any idea of how solve the problem?

Comment: How do you define the colour `myred`? And the command `\mytextsizesmaller`?

Comment: Could you please post a complete code reproducing your problem?

Comment: Hello Bernard, I updated the code by including \myred and \ mytextsizesmaller. Posting the whole code is not possible as too large. Any standard beamer code including  metropolis as theme should be fine though. The code compile without any problem on my macbook pro (I prevented the update to avoid the occurrence of the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared by reinstalling mactex from scratch and by updating all of the packages to the last release. bah.